# difference between AMQP, MOM, JMS and Message broker?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, messaging, messagebroker, mom

I'm getting confused to understand below terms

`Message broker`: Its a application which is having one centralized place to keep messages for transmission / routing.

`AMQP`: Its a an protocol (application) which is basically implemented by message broker applications.

`MOM`: Its a client application to receive and send messages to different applications.

`JMS`: Its also client level application which is extended from MOM.

Please correct if my understating is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

MOM is generally a higher-level concept used to describe architecture and overall design. Message-Oriented-Middleware-- very similar to EDA-- Event Driven Architecture.

Message Broker: Correct, this is the process that receives messages from producers and distributes them to consumers-- in other words *brokering* messages between applications.

AMQP: Is a wire protocol that is used by the broker and clients to agree on how to send messages between each other and support various features-- timestamps, expiration, transactions, etc.

JMS: Is a Java API standard for applications and brokers to adhere to. It is a thin API-only specification and *not* a wire protocol. JMS-compatible brokers, such as ActiveMQ, IBM MQ, etc. implement wire protocols that support the JMS API specification.

To put it all together:

An organization may adopt a Message Oriented Middleware (MOM) in order to decouple applications at runtime. This architecture will be achieved by using JMS-compatible message brokers and JMS-compatible clients that are communicating under the covers using the AMQP wire protocol.

Comment: so MOM is also kind of API which is used to exchange messages between two applications ? Is it correct ? Can you share more about MOM and any example where it can be used ?

Comment: MOM is a high-level and generic term, not a specific API. FWIW-- 'Event Driven Architecture' (aka EDA) is the more modern term that is used in place of MOM these days. ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware